# Cant switch off airplane mode

Tags: networking, rfkill

I have a problem that I can't turn off the airplane mode.
When I typed in a terminal `rfkill Block all`, then `rfkill list all` the output is:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: yes
         Hard blocked: yes
```

Then I typed `rfkill unlock all`, and the output is:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: yes
```

It is also not working with `sudo`. Please help me!